# How to make separate report for different specification files in protractor?

Tags: node.js, selenium, automation, jasmine, protractor

How can we make separate reports for different specification files in protractor?

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}
{
  'browserName': 'internet explorer'
}],

  framework: 'jasmine',

 specs: ['TC_2.js','TC_3.js'],
```

Currently my code will generate HTML report for "chrome" execution in first iteration.When it go next iteration,it will generate report for "FF".In 3rd iteration it will generate report for "IE".However at the end I am getting last iteration(i.e 3rd )internet explorer HTML report at base location.Because this last iteration replacing the report of previous iterations.

Is there a way to get all 3 reports?(i.e Chrome,FF and IE reports)

**protractor-html-screenshot-reporter** is the report I am using.

```
Following is my code:

onPrepare: function() {   
      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
    });  

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'D:/Manoj/TestReport3/',

         docTitle: 'Test Case Execution Details',
         docName: 'BYTestReport.html',
//Meta builder      
  metaDataBuilder: function(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities){
            var metaData = {
                description: descriptions.join('|'),
                 passed: results.passed(),
                 os: 'Windows 7',               
                 browser: {
                  name: capabilities.caps_.browserName
                  , version: capabilities.caps_.version
                }
              };
            if(results.items_.length > 0) {
              var result = results.items_[0];
             metaData.message = result.message;                    
               metaData.trace = result.trace.stack;                         
            }           
return metaData;
}  // Meta Builder ends 
}));
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use browserName as folder name for html report, and jsons, and pngs:
Inside `onPrepare: function(){`

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
        console.log(cap);
        browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'target/'+browser.browserName+'/angular-test-result/',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            preserveDirectory: false
        }));
    });
```

and remove `addReporter` from where you already have it

Your code updated to protractor-html-screenshot-reporter:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

onPrepare: function() {   

     browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);

    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
        console.log(cap);
        browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'target/'+browser.browserName+'/angular-test-result/',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            preserveDirectory: false
        }));
    });
}
```

BTW you have to install reporter: `npm install protractor-html-screenshot-reporter --save-dev`

Comment: I am getting error in the command window as unexpected toke.I have updated my code in the above section.

Could you please help to modify my code to generate separate browser reports?

Comment: I`m not sure what metaDataBuilder is, so I updated my answer with your code update to protractor-html-screenshot-reporter.

Comment: Its working fine.However I am facing some issues with IE browser.I will check and let you know.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different protractor config files for specific specs and trigger those specific e2e suits with different command specifying in package.json passing the config file as parameter.

ex: "specifice2e": "\"ng e2e --protractorConfig=e2e\specificprotractor.conf.js "

And in config file you can mention the folder name where you want to generate seperate report.